# Do you "buy on" or "buy from" online webshops?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Some sites use the prase "**buy on example.com**" when they link to products using some affiliate program. For me "**buy from example.com**" sounds better since you're going to follow that link to example.com and buy the product **from** them.

What would be the reason to use **on**?

Comment: The reason to use *on* is that it means a different thing, namely "on". You can also buy *in*, *at*, *behind*, and they all mean different things.

Comment: And while we're at it, you can also buy *for* and *within* a shop. Probably not at the same time, though.

Comment: You're right. You can express different things depending on what you say. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: good question :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*On* specifies the location, while *from* specifies who the seller was.

You can buy a product *on* the street or *on* my site. You can buy a product *from* me or *from* Amazon.

Comment: Thanks. Both prepositions make perfect sense. _On_ because the product is sold elsewhere and _from_ because seller is someone else.